# How to read $\sqrt[\frac{1}{x}]{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

How do I read $$\sqrt[\frac{1}{x}]{n}$$

I was curious if this was equal to $n^x$. This may sound a weirdly obvious question and instinctively I thought the answer was yes (since a root is a fractional exponent and we are just using the reciprocal here) but I wanted to be sure, and on the usual math sites I never see this used.

Comment: Where did you see this (poor) use of notation?

Comment: One of those "Can you solve this?" problems. I thought it interesting (and find them fun to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt[a]{n}=n^{1/a}$$
is a general rule for the root notation and so:
$$\sqrt[\frac1x]{n}=n^x$$

However one thing to note is that often the root notation means to take the primary root only, so for complex numbers where there are many roots only the primary is taken

Comment: This answer is a good one, but we should probably clarify that $a$, and hence $1/x$, is usually understood to be a positive integer. This is odd since an expression like $1/x$ usually ranges over non-integers. Provided context is clear, the notation could be extended to other real numbers, but IMO that should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @BenW I agree, and to be honest the idea of a rational root makes sense to most people but when we extend it to irrational or non-positive roots it only makes sense to think of these as reciprocal powers

Comment: @HenryLee This was great, thanks, I was just curious if I was missing something obvious.

Comment: @BenW I assumed x was a positive integer, yes.

Comment: @Jesse I hope you mean $1/x$, not plain old $x$.

Comment: @BenW no $x$ as a positive integer as if $1/x$ was a positive integer then we just have a standard root here